Floyd-Steinberg dithering image in grayscale based on input color
I want to create a Floyd-Steinberg dithered image using a specific color as a base. At the end of the dithering process pixels that match the input color will be set to black, otherwise to white (or vice versa).
Like the example images below

The example image above is using the following colors (RGB):
(255, 255, 255)   white
(0, 215, 225)     light_blue
(0, 120, 240)     mid_blue
(0, 0, 120)       dark_blue
(0, 0, 0)         black
This is from https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/a2v5Syk6gJs7HnRoq/computational-thread-art
I have tried to replicated this dithering. But I didn't manage to get the same results.
Example of my result.
Color light_blue :

Color black :

Here is the code for what I have so far.
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

cv::Vec3b FindClosestPaletteColor_(cv::Vec3b Color, const std::vector<cv::Vec3b>& Palette) {
    int MinID = 0;
    cv::Vec3b Difference = Color - Palette[0];
    float MinDistance = cv::norm(Difference);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < Palette.size(); i++) {
        Difference = Color - Palette[i];
        float Distance = cv::norm(Difference);
        if (Distance < MinDistance) {
            MinDistance = Distance;
            MinID = i;
        }
    }
    return Palette[MinID];
}

cv::Mat FloydSteinbergDithering_(cv::Mat InputImage, const std::vector<cv::Vec3b>& ColorPalette) {
    cv::Mat Image = InputImage.clone();
    cv::Mat ResultImage = Image.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < Image.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Image.cols; j++) {
            cv::Vec3b CurrentColor = Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j);
            cv::Vec3b NewPixelColor = FindClosestPaletteColor_(CurrentColor, ColorPalette);
            ResultImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = NewPixelColor;

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                int QuantError = (int)CurrentColor[k] - NewPixelColor[k];
                if (j + 1 < Image.cols)
                    Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j + 1)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j + 1)[k] + (7 * QuantError) / 16);
                if (i + 1 < Image.rows && j - 1 >= 0)
                    Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j - 1)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j - 1)[k] + (3 * QuantError) / 16);
                if (i + 1 < Image.rows)
                    Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j)[k] + (5 * QuantError) / 16);
                if (i + 1 < Image.rows && j + 1 < Image.cols)
                    Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j + 1)[k] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j + 1)[k] + (1 * QuantError) / 16);
            }
        }
    }
    return ResultImage;
}

int main() 
{

    cv::Mat InputImage = cv::imread("TestImage.jpg");
    if (InputImage.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Unable to load input image!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //I have used white as secondary color. But want it to only have 1 color as input in the final version. So it can work with any color
    /*Black*/std::vector<cv::Vec3b> ColorPalette = { cv::Vec3b(0, 0, 0), cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 255) };
///*light Blue*/std::vector<cv::Vec3b> ColorPalette = { cv::Vec3b(225, 215, 0), cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 255) };
    cv::Mat ResultImage = FloydSteinbergDithering_(InputImage, ColorPalette);

    cv::imwrite("output_image.jpg", ResultImage);

    cv::cvtColor(ResultImage, ResultImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::bitwise_not(ResultImage, ResultImage);

    cv::imwrite("GrayScaledImage.jpg", ResultImage);

    cv::imshow("Result Image", ResultImage);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}

Input image


I like the deer. However, you forgot to ask a question.

the point is error diffusion, combined with a palette. at every pixel, you find the closest palette value, and then push the error onwards. any issues you have with that would be due to voluntarily programming in C++. you can totally use Python, with numba to make it fast.

if you want an image mask for each palette entry, you need to store an image of palette indices during the diffusion. if you store the resulting colors only, you'd have to look up the palette entry for each pixel again.

You’re dithering with only black and white, obviously you’ll get a large blue error propagated indefinitely. I think you’re supposed to dither with all those colors, then pick out pixels of each color in a second step.

The only weird thing I see in your dithering code is that you make two copies of the input image, one you use for error propagation and the other as the output image. You can do both in the same copy.

Thanks all for the replies :) Think i understand what your points is. Will see if i can create that. :)

oh also since you clip your errors, that WILL distort the entire thing. you need to work with int16, so that it does NOT clip/saturate. you also need the palette to contain ALL colors you plan to use, not just two.

@ChristophRackwitz I got it working. Posted as answer. But could you please look over the code and see if you can see something that should get done different?
And thank you all for taking the time to answer. :)

So is the goal to have only one color at each pixel position, or a combination?  Could a pixel be both dark blue and mid blue at the same time?

Here’s my thoughts on dithering colors and clamping.
When dithering, we create points of different colors, from a distance these colors mix and we perceive the patch as the average of the colors of the dots. One key takeaway here is that you cannot average two colors to get a third color unless that third color is on the line between the two colors in the color space (assuming linear RGB, the 3rd color will be somewhere on the straight line, in other color spaces the line doesn’t need to be straight). When dithering with 3 colors, we have a triangle of colors on a 2D plane that can be obtained by mixing them. In general, the convex hull of the set of colors (the palette) used for dithering represents all of the colors that we can create by mixing the colors in the palette.
If the input image has colors outside of this convex hull, then those colors cannot be reproduced. The dithering process will introduce an error that will be propagated indefinitely, producing artifacts that might extend for a long time. Imagine a two color dithering with gray and black. The image has a white area. The dithering algorithm will fill this area with gray, and accumulate the difference between that gray and the white, which will cause an area to the right and bottom of this object to be much brighter than it should be, until the difference has been accounted for.
The same would happen with any other color outside the convex hull of the palette.
If the palette does not cover all the colors in the image, if the image has colors that cannot be formed by combinations of those colors, we need to get rid of those colors before dithering.
Clamping the accumulated error is a workaround. It avoids the accumulated error being propagated too far, it prevents non-representable colors to produce huge artifacts. But it also will alter the colors that can be represented, and so it will not produce perfect colors.
The best solution of course is to ensure that the palette we use for dithering always covers the whole gamut used in the image. Instead of picking colors that occur often in the image, we pick colors that form the extremes of the colors in the image. Including saturated red, yellow, green, cyan, blue and magenta, as well as pure white and black, will accomplish this for any RGB image.
If the choice of colors is fixed, as is the case here, then the best solution is to pre-process the input image to remove colors outside of the convex hull of the palette, and replace them by colors inside. This is not a complex process, but needs a bit of thought to be done right.
Clamping is a very simple and cheap solution, but it is sub-optimal.

A quick example. I'm using an image with tweaked colors to make them brighter, so that the effect is more noticeable.

Let's first dither using only black, white, red, green and blue. Note that you cannot make bright yellow using these colors, if you average red and green you get something more akin to orange or brown than yellow. The dithering process adds white to try to make things brighter, but it is still accumulating a large error that gets propagated down and to the right, changing the dark lettering and dark lines:

If we add pure yellow to the palette, errors do not accumulate, the yellow in the image can be formed by mixing colors from our palette:

When we dither without using yellow, and clip the error to be within the range [0 255] for each channel, the error doesn't accumulate as much, and so doesn't get propagated as far, yet it is still there, and we can still observe how the diagonal lines at the top-left and bottom-right of the sign, and the letters, appear thinner than they should be and have a green halo. There's also a bright line along the bottom-right side of the sign:

If we had clipped in input pixel values to be within the convex hull of the palette, there wouldn't be any error accumulating.

I learned long ago to make sure my palette always includes the 8 corners of the color cube.

Thank you for this good answer, and thank you for taking the time to help :) Keep up the good work :)

If you also want to understand and learn more about Floyd Steinberg Dithering. javidx9 made a good youtube video explaining this topic.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lseR6ZguBNY
Working solution.
cv::Scalar FindNearestColor(const cv::Scalar& Color, const std::vector<cv::Scalar>& Palettes)
{
    double MinimumDistance = DBL_MAX;
    cv::Scalar NearestColor;
    for (const auto& CurrentColor : Palettes)
    {
        double Distance = norm(Color - CurrentColor);
        if (Distance < MinimumDistance)
        {
            MinimumDistance = Distance;
            NearestColor = CurrentColor;
        }
    }
    return NearestColor;
}

void FloydSteinbergDithering(cv::Mat& Image, const std::vector<cv::Scalar>& Palettes, optional<vector<cv::Mat>>* Masks = nullptr)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> TempMasks;
    if(Masks != nullptr && Masks->has_value())
    {
        TempMasks.resize(Palettes.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Palettes.size(); ++i)
        {
            TempMasks[i] = cv::Mat::zeros(Image.size(), CV_8UC1);
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < Image.rows; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Image.cols; ++x)
        {
            cv::Scalar CurrentColor(Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x));
            cv::Scalar NewColor = FindNearestColor(CurrentColor, Palettes);
            Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = cv::Vec3b(NewColor[0], NewColor[1], NewColor[2]);

            if (Masks != nullptr && Masks->has_value())
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < Palettes.size(); ++i)
                {
                    if (NewColor == Palettes[i])
                    {
                        TempMasks[i].at<uchar>(y, x) = 255;
                    }
                }
            }

            cv::Scalar QuantizationError = CurrentColor - NewColor;
            auto AddQuantizationError = [&](int y, int x, double Factor)
            {
                if (x >= 0 && x < Image.cols && y >= 0 && y < Image.rows)
                {
                    cv::Scalar Pixel(Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x));
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                    {
                        Pixel[i] += QuantizationError[i] * Factor;
                        Pixel[i] = clamp(Pixel[i], 0.0, 255.0);
                    }
                    Image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = cv::Vec3b(Pixel[0], Pixel[1], Pixel[2]);
                }
            };

            AddQuantizationError(y, x + 1, 7.0 / 16);
            AddQuantizationError(y + 1, x - 1, 3.0 / 16);
            AddQuantizationError(y + 1, x, 5.0 / 16);
            AddQuantizationError(y + 1, x + 1, 1.0 / 16);
        }
    }

    if (Masks != nullptr && Masks->has_value())
    {
        Masks->emplace(std::move(TempMasks));
    }
}

int main() 
{
    vector<cv::Scalar> ColorPalette =
    {
        cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0),       // Black
        cv::Scalar(120, 0, 0),     // Dark Blue
        cv::Scalar(240, 120, 0),   // Mid Blue
        cv::Scalar(225, 215, 0),   // Light Blue
        cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255)  // White
    };

    cv::Mat Image = cv::imread("Image.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (Image.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open or find the image!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Optional vector to store masks
    optional<vector<cv::Mat>> Masks = vector<cv::Mat>();

    FloydSteinbergDithering(Image, ColorPalette, &Masks);
    if (Masks.has_value()) 
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < Masks->size(); ++k)
        {
            std::string filename = "Mask_Color_" + std::to_string(k) + ".png";
            if (!cv::imwrite(filename, Masks->at(k))) 
            {
                std::cerr << "Error writing mask to file: " << filename << std::endl;
               
            }
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("Dithered Image", Image);
    cv::imwrite("Dithered_Image.jpg", Image);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}


You'll get better results if you don't clamp the pixel values when propagating the error. Clamping means you're erasing information. So you need to cast the image to a larger type (e.g. 16-bit signed integer, or float which is always more convenient). When you do this cast, you can simultaneously add a 1 pixel border to the left, right and bottom sides of the image. With that border, you can then remove the tests for out-of-bounds access, making the program significantly faster.

Also, your FindNearestColor() should return the palette index, rather than the color. Because right after that you're looking for the index by iterating through the palette again, which seems silly.

If i dont do this "clamp(Pixel[i], 0.0, 255.0);" I get some werd artifacts ? Scalar is using double? So shouldent that be correct?

The Image in which you write the new values is uint8 (unless I'm missing a cast, I don't see one). So if you don't clamp your values, writing them into the image will cause overflow (which wraps, 256 will be written as 0). This is obviously bad, clamping is better than overflowing. But if  you cast your image to int16, or to float, then the propagated error shouldn't be overflowing, and you won't need the cast any more.

i did try converting the full image to 16 bit. But i returned back to this since i got the same weird artifacts if i didn't clamp. But i also think it was weird adding clamp. But when looking at the video and code from the youtube video javidx9 posted. He also did use clamp. So i was thinking that it was supposed to do that even if i think i didn't make sense from the description of the algorithm?

"Somebody else also used clamp" is not really a good argument. It's not like being able to post a video on YouTube is a good selector for understanding of image processing algorithms. What kind of weird artifacts did you get?

I modified your code to do OriginalImage.convertTo(Image, CV_16S); at the top of FloydSteinbergDithering() (with the first input argument renamed to OriginalImage, and Image.convertTo(OriginalImage, CV_8U); at the end of that function. This required changing all cv::Vec3b to cv::Vec3s. I could then remove the clamp line just fine. There's not a huge difference in the output, I'll admit. But it should be more correct.

@CrisLuengo
That was what i did before i ended up with the code abow. But if you try endering only black and white. You get artifacts :/

Right, that's because you can't dither a color image using only black and white. I already commented on that.

@CrisLuengo Someting is wrong whan you dont clamp. With 5 color the image looks the same. But with 4 colors or less the clamped image looks bether, and dont have weird artifacts. Here is a image with 4 colors with no clamping = https://imgur.com/wB8EsIn. Than same  with clamping = https://imgur.com/Gixq9hJ. And if we use 3 colors. No clamp = https://imgur.com/61N2VwA, with clamp = https://imgur.com/o6FI078.

I’ve written down my thoughts about your artifact problem as an answer, because a comment is not a good place for that. I don’t have code for you, maybe I’ll have some time to write some eventually.

I've added a simple example demonstrating the excessive error propagation, and what effect it has.
